# Adding page numbers to pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Box from './Box'

// Styles
import '../../App.css'

class Container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            page: 0
        }
    }

    showPreviousPage = () => {
        this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
    }

    showNextPage = () => {
        this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
    }

    render () {
        const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

        const itemsToDisplay = 9

        const startIndex = this.state.page * itemsToDisplay;

        const visibleItems = items.slice(startIndex, startIndex + itemsToDisplay)

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="box-container">
                    {visibleItems.map(id => <Box id={id} key={id} />)}
                </div>
                <div className="main-pagination">
                    <div className="pagination">
                        <button onClick={this.showPreviousPage}>Previous Page</button>
                        <button onClick={this.showNextPage}>Next Page</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Container
```

The code perfectly renders the `<Box>` components that I want to render, 9 components per page. However, I have two questions here:

1. How to implement a "stop" mechanism, so that when the user reaches the final page, the `<Next Page>` button becomes inactive (And `<Previous Page>` should be inactive on first page)?
2. How to add 10 page numbers in between the `<Previous Page>` and `<Next Page>` buttons? So that it looks `<Previous Page> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 <Next Page>`, and updates to 11 12 .... when user reaches the 10-th page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [react-js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination) which gives the features that you need.

You just need to install it via npm and replace your pagination code

```
<div className="main-pagination">
      <div className="pagination">
           <button onClick={this.showPreviousPage}>Previous Page</button>
            <button onClick={this.showNextPage}>Next Page</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<Pagination
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          itemsCountPerPage={10}
          totalItemsCount={450}
          pageRangeDisplayed={5}
          onChange={yourOnChangeMethod}
        />
```

Changing your items when a page is changed can be done using onChange method.
And you can use your state to set Pagination easily.

Comment: Let me know if you are looking to implement it completely without using an existing component. I can suggest you on how to do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just noticed your comment. Yes, I'd like to do that using the existing one, I tried the package you've recommended, and couldn't make it work properly.

Comment: will you be able to post issue that you are facing?

Comment: I'm getting the pagination (though the CSS is weird). Can't figure out how to link the <Box> component's amount on pages with pagination, it doesn't change anything when I click on page numbers. Here in this code you could see I linked it an array of numbers. I can increase the amount of Boxes by simply adding more numbers to the array. Another moment I didn't like was that I had to specify the max number of pages, whereas in this case it just goes on the more numbers I add in the array.

Comment: It doesnt change anything -> you have to handle onChange method as specified in answer. And number of boxes in your scenario will be the max number of pages. You can give some number to itemsCountPerPage which gives proper pagination for you

Comment: But how to link that number to the ID of the box? I need the Box ID to pass it down as props. The ID's are range of numbers from 1,2,....

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'll give another try to it.